# How do you get something like window.location.host while in a vuex SSR?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am creating the client side of the xyz.com sites and the abc.xyz.com subdomain. Both sites use the same Vue / Nuxt source code
Working with API: xyz.com/api... and abc.xyz.com/api... via vuex. But I don't understand how do you get something like window.location.host from [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location) while in a vuex?

```
// state
export default () => ({
    api: window.location.host
})

// getters
getLocation = state => state.api // ReferenceError - window is not defined
```

Can I do this without plugins?

Comment: window is a client-side object, there is no "window" in SSR. in SSR you can use req.url to capture the url.

Comment: What is the end goal?

Comment: @kissu fetch data from xyz.com/api... or abc.xyz.com/api... , before first mount app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I used nuxtServerInit and req.headers.host:

```
nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    const { host } = req.headers

    if (host) {
        commit('setHost', host)
        commit('setUrl', `https://${host}/`)
        commit('setApi', `https://${host}/api/v1`)
    }
}
```